# Is there a superior leveling system to avoid lippage in tile flooring?

Tags: flooring, tile, leveling

My question is, is there a superior tile leveling system for large format (13x20) floor tile to avoid any lippage?  There are several styles on the market; spacer clips and wedges' spacers and pommels, spacers and caps, spacer clips and rings, spacer straps and caps, and spacer plates and spindles.  Most systems except the pommels and rings require some type of hand tool that utilizes mechanical advantage to tune the system.  Some have a simple one step process for removal post installation.  Most have a reusable component.  Which one does the best job for the least effort and upfront cost?

This info is not necessarily specific to my question, but I am going to be laying a new tile floor in our home entry way, an alcove, and a small half bath.  All surfaces total ~150 sq. ft.  I will be laying the tile with an 1/8" grout line on a diagonal running bond.  I will also back butter the tile.  The sub-floor is a concrete slab and I will be floating a self leveling compound.  I am a DIY'er with no tile experience.

Answer (score 1):

One of the newest and most comprehensive tile leveling systems on the market that I deal with is the Spin Doctor Tile Leveling System by RTC.  It is tool-less, can be used as spacers in addition to leveling, and is relatively easy to use.  RTC has a video on youtube video showing how to use it: https://youtu.be/NwP1OW1-7L0

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.  I think I'm going to to give the Spin Doctor a shot.

Comment: Update:  I used the Spin Doctor leveling system and my job looks fantastic. I'll try to get some pictures posted.